# iPhone is not receiving token from Instagram API via implicit auth

Tags: javascript, ios, instagram

When using Android with Chrome, Windows with Chrome, Macbook with Safari everything works fine. The problem is with iPhones only.

Normally I would get a response like:

http://redirecturl.com/#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

With iPhone I am getting only:

http://redirecturl.com/

I need to access the # value with javascript so I'm using:

```
location.hash
```

I have also tried the following to get the full address:

```
location.href
```

But none is getting me the hash values provided by Instagram.

Either Instagram is not responding with the #access_token or the "clever" iPhone is whipping with it all when receiving the response.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get one: server-side or client-side. The second option (called implicit authentication) can only be used when implicit OAuth is enabled in the client settings

> (Manage Clients > Edit Client > Security > Disable implicit OAuth).

It is disabled by default.

In either case, you need to redirect the user to the authorization URL to obtain an access token.
The URL for explicit mode:- Server Side [API Link](https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code)

The URL for implicit mode:- Client Side [API Link](https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token)

After this, you will be redirected to the REDIRECT-URI, which will be passed an argument. For explicit mode this will be a query string with a code, while for the implicit mode you will get the access token directly to a hash:

```
your-redirect-uri?code=CODE
your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

For implicit mode, you can then get the access token from the `window.location.hash` in Javascript.

Comment: that is exactly what's not working window.location.hash, only with iPhone